# Returning to previous line with Vim

Tags: vim, vi

I was wondering if there's a way to return to the previous line you were on in Vim.

Say, for example, I'm writing C code and I just wanted to add an `#include` at the top of the page: I press `gg` and go to the top, add the `#include`, and then I want to return to the line I left off of.

Is this possible in Vim?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Yes. You can use ``` `` ``` in order to jump between the last two positions.

Otherwise, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> can help you. See `:help CTRL-I`.

Comment: @Amit also try `g;` and `g,`, it is go to position previous/next change. Sometimes it suits better then `<C-o>`/`<C-i>`.

Comment: @Zyx: Thank you, I'll definitely use that.

Comment: @Zyx: True, I had completely forgotten that one!

Comment: does `help: CTRL-I` usually send you to a browser window or is that only in pycharm?

Answer (score 38):

Use a mark:

```
ma
```

marks the spot (before the `gg`)

```
`a
```

brings you back.

Comment: Another good way to do it. Though, sometimes you want to go back and you didn't think about setting a mark.

Comment: I know but for some reason `\`` rarely seems to bring me where I think it should :)

Comment: Ahh I see. uh oh. It worked for me when I just tried it. Is it iffy on line locations?

Comment: It's not iffy, I just never got used to how it marks the "last location".

Comment: Actually, the `\`` syntax remember positions before *long jumps* (not h, j, k, l for example)